# What does っぽくなってきたぜ! mean?

Tags: expressions

I have some trouble with this expression. It's by itself, on a sticker, without anything else before or after. I know っぽい can mean "-ish" and that with なる it usually means "tend to become" but since there is no adjective here I don't get it. "Become something like" what?

Comment: Like you guess, this basically means something like _"[This] got really [this]-ish!"_ Depends on context as to what the "this" refers to.  Does the sticker have any specific design, such as maybe it's in the shape of a fish?  Or is the sticker on something specific, like a fancy car or coffee mug?  Look for context cues.  If there are none, this might just be a meme-ish sticker intended for humorous purposes -- put it on yourself, and _"I just got really me-ish!"_  

Comment: Thank you for your reply. No, it's a very simple sticker from the latest Slam Dunk movie. Just the face of Hanamichi with that sentence. Actually, I realized in the movie Hanamichi says that sentence to Akagi, saying "ゴルっぽくなってきたぜ", which in my head was something like "Now that's the Gorilla (his nickname) I know". So maybe the sticker, without a word preceding っぽく, basically means "Now that's the you I know!" or something like that

Answer (score 3):

(っ)ぽい is basically a suffix ("-ish"), but in very informal speech, it is sometimes used like a standalone adjective meaning それっぽい or "authentic-looking/-sounding", "believable", "plausible", and so on. For example,

> 「鳥山明みたいな絵を描いてみたよ。」「すごい、ぽい！」

> あんまり、ぽくなくない？
> It's not very realistic, is it?

In your case, the sticker means something like "it's becoming more authentic" or "(finally) this is like the real thing". Looks like this is a phrase from SLAM DUNK, so I assume it was originally said with sufficient context. For example, if this is said during a boring basketball game, it would be interpreted as "Finally, this is real basketball!". But you can use the same phrase when something different from your expectations has finally become exciting.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. It is a sentence from Slam Dunk. It's actually a very simple sticker from the latest movie. Just the face of Hanamichi with that sentence. Actually, I realized in the movie Hanamichi says that sentence to Akagi, saying "ゴルっぽくなってきたぜ", which in my head was something like "Now that's the Gorilla (his nickname) I know". So maybe the sticker, without a word preceding っぽく, basically means "Now that's the you I know!" or something like that

Comment: But I guess it could also mean "Finally that's the real thing", similar to "Now we're talking!" Maybe you could give several nuances to the sticker?

Comment: An English slang expression that's adjacent to this general slangy adjective sense of っぽい is "legit".